# ScrollViewer scrollbutton goes off the page

Tags: silverlight

I have a `ContentControl` with a `DataGrid` in it - all within a `ScrollViewer`. I need the `DataGrid` to scroll by the `ScrollViewer` and not itself. Currently when the `DataGrid` is larger than the `ScrollViewer` the Vertical scrollbar appears, but it goes beyond the bottom border - I added a pic to show this. How do I get the `Scrollbar` to stop at the bottom of the `ScrollViewer`? XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer Name="scvDG" Style="{StaticResource scrBarV}" Margin="24,217,22,0"
    VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="526" VerticalAlignment="Top"
    BorderBrush="Transparent" Foreground="Transparent" 
    BorderThickness="0" MaxHeight="526">
  <ContentControl Width="756" Height="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
    <sdk:DataGrid x:Name="dgStaff" Margin="0,4" Width="756" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
       AutoGenerateColumns="False" Background="#FFB7ADE5" Style="{StaticResource dg}" 
       Visibility="Visible" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="Auto" 
       HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Top">
    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
    ...
    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
  </sdk:DataGrid>
  </ContentControl>
</ScrollViewer>
```

[image]

Let me know if there is other info you need.

Answer (score 1):

Its better to remove the content control since it takes the grid inside,

This works

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
 <ScrollViewer Name="scvDG"   Margin="34,105,12,0"
 VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Height="195" VerticalAlignment="Top"
 BorderBrush="Transparent" Foreground="Transparent" 
 BorderThickness="0" MaxHeight="526">
 <sdk:DataGrid x:Name="dgStaff" Margin="0,4" Width="756" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
 AutoGenerateColumns="False" Background="#FFB7ADE5"  
 Visibility="Visible" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="600" 
 HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" VerticalContentAlignment="Top">
 </sdk:DataGrid>
 </ScrollViewer>
```

Comment: It does not change anything for me and my DataGrid loses it's DataBinding.

Comment: The screen shot looks the same as above. I found the solution!

Comment: I always do  =) I gave you a +1 for your time!

Answer (score 0):

I did not realize it would override the scrollviewer, but it did. This is the Style for that crasy fun-wide scrollbar. Look in the `RowDefinition` part.

```
<Style x:Key="scrBarV" TargetType="ScrollViewer">
<Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Right" />
<Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
<Setter Property="VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Visible" />
<Setter Property="Padding" Value="4" />
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
<Setter Property="BorderBrush">
  <Setter.Value>
    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
      <GradientStop Color="#FFA3AEB9" Offset="0" />
      <GradientStop Color="#FF8399A9" Offset="0.375" />
      <GradientStop Color="#FF718597" Offset="0.375" />
      <GradientStop Color="#FF617584" Offset="1" />
    </LinearGradientBrush>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
<Setter Property="Template">
  <Setter.Value>
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ScrollViewer">
      <Border CornerRadius="2" BorderBrush="{StaticResource hdrLGB}" BorderThickness="2">
        <Grid>
          <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <!--<RowDefinition Height="665" WRONG />-->
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />  <!--<RIGHT />-->
          </Grid.RowDefinitions>
          <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
          </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ScrollContentPresenter x:Name="ScrollContentPresenter" 
                                  Cursor="{TemplateBinding Cursor}" 
                                  Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                  ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" />
          <Rectangle Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Fill="#FFE9EEF4" />
          <ScrollBar x:Name="VerticalScrollBar" Width="50" IsTabStop="False" 
                     Visibility="{TemplateBinding ComputedVerticalScrollBarVisibility}" 
                     Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Orientation="Vertical" 
                     ViewportSize="{TemplateBinding ViewportHeight}" 
                     Maximum="{TemplateBinding ScrollableHeight}" Minimum="0" 
                     Value="{TemplateBinding VerticalOffset}" Margin="0,-1,-1,-1" />
        </Grid>
      </Border>
    </ControlTemplate>
  </Setter.Value>
</Setter>
</Style>
```

Thanks for helping!